# Smallest $b\in[0,1]$ s.t. $n-\lfloor n/3\rfloor\le bn$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality, optimization

What is the smallest $b\in[0,1]$ such that for all integer $n\ge 1$
$$
n-\lfloor n/3\rfloor\le bn
$$
Some post says that $n-\lfloor n/3\rfloor=\lceil 2n/3\rceil$ so the greatest lower bound is quite intuitive which is $2n/3$. However, while I know $\lceil 2n/3\rceil\le 2n/3+2/3$
due to an inequality for $x,y>0$ we have
$$
\lceil x/y\rceil \le \frac{x+(y-1)}{y} 
$$
I still cannot solve for $b$ here. (Above is actually the input size to a recursive algorithm, finding $bn$ allows us to apply master theorem to calculate run time easily)

[1] [Why is $\lfloor n/3 \rfloor + \lceil 2n/3\rceil = n?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2374991/897319)

Comment: Note that, for $n = 1$, we have $n - \lfloor n/3\rfloor = 1 - \lfloor 1/3\rfloor = 1$, so then with your expression, we get $1 \le b$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comment we have $1\le b$ due to the $n=1$ case. However, I forgot that we may still use $b=2/3$ in master theorem, in fact from the persepective of master theorem, $2n/3,\lfloor 2n/3\rfloor, \lceil 2n/3\rceil$ are the same.

To see why, try to solve for $b\in[0,1]$ from $n-\lfloor n/3\rfloor = \lceil 2n/3\rceil \le 2n/3+2/3\le bn$. We have

$$
2/3+2/(3n) \le b
$$

which tends to $2/3$ for sufficiently large $n$.